# Appending to Excel Spreadsheets in Perl on Windows AND Linux

Tags: windows, linux, perl, excel, append

I want to append to an Excel spreadsheet. Win32::OLE works perfectly with this, but it doesn't work on Linux machines. Spreadsheet::WriteExcel doesn't seem to be able to append while it can work on both platforms. I found out about Excel::Writer::XLSX, but it reports that it does not have as many features as Spreadsheet...

I would also like to create hyperlinks, so clicking on some text will lead you to another sheet in the Excel workbook. Is this possible and on which one (Excelwriter/etc)?

So two questions:
1) What should I use so I can append to spreadsheets while working on both platforms?'
2) Is it possible to create hyperlinks to lead to other sheets and using which one?

Here is the code I used for Win32::OLE that appended a new worksheet:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
print "Opening Excel...\n";

$Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
   || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');

#appending to existing excel file
my $book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($full_name) || die "Error: Could not open Excel workbook";

#putting this sheet at the beginning
my $sheet = $book->Worksheets->Add({Before => $book->Worksheets(1)}) or die "Error: " . Win32::OLE->LastError;
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to show some code.

Comment: Why? All I want to do is append to a file on both platforms and create hyperlinks to link to other sheets. I don't KNOW what code to use right now and don't even know if it's possible. I'll add code though to show what I did using win32::OLE if that helps I guess?

Answer (score 0):

This is partial and maybe a non-valid answer:

Use the open XML SDK for office. Any of the *.xlsx files are actually *.zip files with many xml files inside that describe the document. Using the sdk you could make links between spreadsheets and workbooks. Unfortunately it works on Windows only... :(

Comment: Yeah, it has to work on Windows AND Linux... Thanks anyways though. So you don't know of any other method in say Spreadsheet::WriteExcel that can create hyperlinks to other sheets?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not. Although I was wondering if you could use the OpenOffice SDK to do what you need to achieve? It still uses the same Open Xml Spec and you can download the schema for it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=15805380-F2C0-4B80-9AD1-2CB0C300AEF9